# Linear Regression & Machine Learning Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Good day devs,

I am currently working on Linear Regression with Machine Learning.

The module sklearn.linear_model method Linear_regresion works just fine but throws an error when I try plotting the graph with matplotlib.pyplot plot() method.

You can find my code below:

```
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pandas.read_csv('cost_revenue.csv')

data.describe()

#The CSV file contains 5034 entries. 

X = DataFrame(data, columns=['production_budget_usd'])

Y = DataFrame(data, columns=['worldwide_gross_usd'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(X, Y, alpha=0.3)

plt.title('Film Cost vs Global Revenue')
plt.xlabel('Production Budget $')
plt.ylabel('Worldwide Gross $')

plt.ylim(0, 3000000000)
plt.xlim(0, 450000000)
plt.show()

#This plots a scatterplot and works just fine.

regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, Y)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(X, y, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(X, regression.predict(X), color= 'red', linewidth=3)

plt.title('Film Cost vs Global Revenue')
plt.xlabel('Production budget $')
plt.ylabel('worldwide gross $')
plt.ylim(0,3000000000)
plt.xlim(0,450000000)
plt.show()

#This is the part pf the code where it throws an exception
```

It is suppose to draw a linear regression line on the graph but it throws 3 errors which. I haven’t been able to debug and I will appreciate any possible help.

The errors are:
Typeerror
Keyerror
InvalidIndexerror

Debugging from top to bottom

Comment: Could you add the whole error message?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

Comment: I think theres a little typo here that may be causing the problem: `plt.scatter(X, y, alpha=0.3)`. Notice this is `y`, not `Y`. Is `y` defined somewhere else?

Comment: TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [124], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
      2 plt.scatter(X, y, alpha=0.3)
----> 3 plt.plot(X, regression.predict(X), color= 'red', linewidth=3)
      5 plt.title('Film Cost vs Global Revenue')
      6 plt.xlabel('Production budget $')

Comment: File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

Comment: File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

Comment: File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:487, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    484         kw[prop_name] = val
    486 if len(xy) == 2:
--> 487     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
    488     y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489 else:

Comment: OK, I think I get the picture, I'm wondering more about where the variable `y` comes from.

Comment: File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py:1327, in _check_1d(x)
   1321 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
   1322     warnings.filterwarnings(
   1323         "always",
   1324         category=Warning,
   1325         message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
-> 1327     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328     # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329     # cast to a numpy array.
   1330     if len(w) > 0:

Comment: This was a typo while debugging. 

Y is the defined variable. 

X = DataFrame(data, columns=['production_budget_usd'])

Y = DataFrame(data, columns=['worldwide_gross_usd'])

X and Y are the variables to plot

Comment: OK, you're sure that error comes up with `Y`? because I see `y` in your error message. I also copied your code and managed to run it without error by replacing `y` with `Y`

Comment: Hey Dev David. 

The gentleman below gave the answer to the question where i had to use the .value method before plotting the graph and that works perfectly. 

It seems the issue was never the variable Y or y.  

Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

just change plt.scatter(X, Y, alpha=0.3) to plt.scatter(X, y, alpha=0.3) and you should have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may be in the way you are passing the "X" and "Y" values to the "scatter" and "plot" methods in matplotlib. Sklearn's LinearRegression model expects the input data to be in the form of 2D arrays, whereas the DataFrame you pass only contains 1 column.

Have you tried converting X and Y into 2D arrays using the DataFrame's values attribute and passing this to the adjustment and prediction methods

```
X = DataFrame(data, columns=['production_budget_usd']).values
Y = DataFrame(data, columns=['worldwide_gross_usd']).values

regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, Y)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(X, Y, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(X, regression.predict(X), color= 'red', linewidth=3)
```

One question, is the data file "cost_revenue.csv" loaded correctly, and does it contain the expected data?

Comment: You gave the perfect Answer. Thank you so much. 

That worked perfectly

Comment: Nicely, glad I was able to help.